# How to loop over a updatable list?

Tags: java

I'm building a Java Running class that will treat a set of items one by one. When working (`run`ning), that set may be updated (items added only).

How can I loop over that list by being sure that it will take into consideration newly added elements?

### Update

Following the answers, I implemented the code that [I suggested on Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/80243/queue-like-system-to-check-existence-of-email).

Comment: @user1933888  - Still the *updated values are not guaranteed to be visible*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a queue (for example, java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue) instead of a list. Queues are specifically designed for this kind of scenario.

Comment: You are talking about Java Queue or Queue systems like "Redis" ?

Comment: I am talking about the Java queue, for example, the LinkedBlockingQueue class from java.util.concurrent.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Since I will run the runnable element from asyncs with the use of Promise, is LinkedBlockingQueue the best choice ? (sorry I'm just discovering Queue)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite get what you're asking.

Comment: @CyrilN. - Well, the performance of `BlockingQueues` will be bad when compared to `Lists`.  But if you want the elements to be *visible*, you need to use a blocking queue.

Comment: If you want to see, I wrote the code and suggested it on Code Review at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/80243/queue-like-system-to-check-existence-of-email

Answer (score 4):

### Answer

You shoud use a `Queue`, i.e. `java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue`, `java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue`, `java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue` or one of the other implementations that suits your needs.

They have different methods which allow you to implement different scenarios. You can check [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) for differences between `Queue` methods (there are methods throwing exceptions, or returning nulls; methods for viewing elements or for retrieving them with removal).

> Throws exception       Returns special value
>
> Insert          add(e)                            offer(e)
>
> Remove        remove()                       poll()
>
> Examine      element()                      peek()

In case of `BlockingQueue` implementations there are additionally 2 options: blocking methods and methods that time out. The extended table for possible methods is in it's [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html).

Choose carefully the required implementation. Do you want a fixed capacity? Do you want to block on retrieval from empty queue?  Do you want your Queue bounded or unbounded. If still in doubt, look up Stack Overflow answers that explain differences between different queue types, Google them or check javadocs.

### RANT

There is one problem you may or may not run into, depending on your design - how to tell the queue is empty because you are done producing elements. Is your producer (whatever is inserting elements into your queue) not fast enough to add items to the queue before they are consumed? Or is the queue empty because all the tasks where completed? In the latter case, if you use a blocking queue, you can block on retrieval of element when there will be none available. You can consider a non-blocking queue in such case, using a "poison pill" marker element that means the producers are done producing, or even better decouple producer from consumer by using an intermediary mediator class which holds the queue and producer / consumer interact only with the mediator.

Comment: If you want to see, I wrote the code and suggested it on Code Review at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/80243/queue-like-system-to-check-existence-of-email

Comment: I did post a short answer with a few tips there.

Answer (score 1):

Don't go with List.

If I you use a `Queue` instance then you can call `remove()` and you would retrieve the elements in FIFO order.  If you use an `List` instance then you can make no such guarantee.

Take the following code as an example:

```
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    list.add(5);
    list.add(4);
    list.add(3);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(1);


    list.set(4,5);
    list.set(3,4);
    list.set(2,3);
    list.set(1,2);
    list.set(0,1);

    System.out.println(list);
```

Also, another difference is abstraction.  With a `Queue` instance you don't have to worry about indexes and this makes things easier to think about if you don't need everything a `List` has to offer.